# Radeon HD 5670 power requirements

Tags: power-supply, power, high-definition

I'm looking at a HP PC HPE-510t, this HP PC only got a 300W power supply, how can it run HD 5670 video card, which requires minimum 400W power supply?

The reason why I ask is because currently I have a HP DC7800, which has a 365W 80% efficient power supply. I installed a HD 5670 video card today, and seem running fine on my 365w power supply, played unreal, left 4 dead2 on max settings.

Here's my power supply label: 12A + 14.5A = 26.5A on 12V rail

I'm also wondering with this power supply, can I use HD 5770 video card, which require minimum 450w power supply.

The power supply calculator shows that my current system without video card only uses about 200w power, which has about 165w power left unused.

Answer (score 0):

Well, some PSU manufacturers advertise their peak rating instead of the continuous output, which is about 30-40% below peak.  Since AMD doesn't want to get blamed for power supplies catching fire, they take that into account on their specs.  Also some PSUs don't have a good allocation of wattage to the different rails.

That said, I'd go with more than a 300W supply if you want to run a gaming system.  Many current CPUs are rated at 125-130W, then you must add motherboard, disk drives, and add-in cards.  But if you're sure that your PSU is rated for 300W continuous, and you aren't running multiple hard disks or a high power CPU, you're probably ok.

Just stay away from the burn-in benchmarks, [the HD 5770 is capable of pulling over 130W](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2856/13).